# Unable to insert into table after creating an After insert trigger

Tags: mysql, triggers

I have two tables 
Table one: `default_sellers_commissions` have:

```
id
value - INT
```

Table two:  `marketplace_saleperpartner` have:

```
id
userID
commission - INT default '0.00'
commission_id
```

What I need is after insert a new row in table `marketplace_saleperpartner` update the `marketplace_saleperpartner.commission` value with value from `default_sellers_commissions.value` where the `marketplace_saleperpartner.commission_id = default_sellers_commissions.id`

So I create a trigger :

```
CREATE TRIGGER `marketplacedefaultcommission`
AFTER INSERT ON `marketplace_saleperpartner`
FOR EACH ROW
UPDATE marketplace_saleperpartner
    SET `marketplace_saleperpartner`.`commision` = `default_sellers_commissions`.`value`
    WHERE `marketplace_saleperpartner`.`comm_id` = `default_sellers_commissions`.`id`
    AND `marketplace_saleperpartner`.`commision`='0.00';
```

P.S:
For some reason I need the  `marketplace_saleperpartner.commision` to insert for the first time with value='0.00'

Now I am getting this error while trying to insert a new row into table marketplace_saleperpartner

```
MySql Error: Can't update table in stored function/trigger because it is already used by statement which invoked this stored function/trigger
```

Any help please ?

Comment: What does the insert statement look like? You cannot modify any of the table row values in a `AFTER` trigger. If you really need to create the row with a commission value of 0, then you'll need to do 2 inserts, as you cannot insert rows in the same table with a trigger. You can set the commission value to a value from a different table. Is that what you are trying to do?

Comment: @JRD Yes this is what I need,  set the commission value to a value from a different table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a `BEFORE INSERT` trigger that sets `marketplace_saleperpartner.commision` to `value` from `marketplace_saleperpartner`.

```
CREATE TRIGGER marketplacedefaultcommission
BEFORE INSERT ON marketplace_saleperpartner
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    SET new.commission = (
        SELECT value
        FROM   default_sellers_commissions
        WHERE  id = new.commission_id
    );
END;
```

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/bdcdfe/2) example